# What is "localcomputer" or domain and how to get it?

Tags: sql-server, windows, azure, windows-10

I am trying to install a program (Microsoft SQL Data Sync Agent), and in one step it is asking me the following:

```
Enter the account you want to run Windows Service under. E.g. domain\user. localcomputer\localuser.
The account must have network access to reach Microsoft SQL Data Sync Service through your network's proxy.
User name: "I have to insert something here"
password "this is another entry"
```

I don't quite get what they are asking me for, I guess the user name is the domain\user that they mentioned, but how can I get that information?

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler than it looks.

During the installation process, you are prompted for an account which has
network access. This account which will be used to run the agent system service.

Use any account you find suitable that has network access which is required to
access the SQL database server over the network.
If the computer is on a domain, use a domain account, otherwise a local account.

If the SQL Server is installed on the same computer as the Data Sync Agent,
you could use the same account that you used for its installation.

For more information, see
[Getting started with SQL Data Sync](https://www.mattmasson.com/2012/07/getting-started-with-sql-data-sync/).